# CSS selector for separate groups of sibling elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to select multiple adjacent elements with css, the *+* selector only selects one, how can I do it?

```
<h2 class="title">Bat</h2>
<h3>Black</h3>
<h3>Cool</h3>
<h2 class="title">Crow</h2>
<h3>Smart</h3>
<h3>Player</h3>
```

Like in this example above, I want to style Bat h3s and Crow h3s differently.

Comment: It may also make sense to group your sets using an HTML5 tag such as `section` for better structure.

Comment: @isherwood: Semantically that is no different from a series of h2 and h3 elements - the only benefit it has is CSS selector scoping as the subheadings won't all share the same parent.

Comment: There is a reason why the html structure is like this, I have no control on this. I don't know in advance how much h3s I will have after each h2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tilde:

```
h2 ~ h3 {
 color:blue;
}
```

This would select all `h3` following a `h2` you can add a special class to the h2 and select adjecent siblings for that class. Along the lines of:

HTML:

```
<h2 class="title bat">Bat</h2>
<h3>Black</h3>
<h3>Cool</h3>
<h2 class="title crow">Crow</h2>
<h3>Smart</h3>
<h3>Player</h3>
```

CSS:

```
h2.bat ~ h3 {
 color:blue;
}
h2.crow ~ h3 {
  color:red;
}
```

Or even select it based upon `:nth-child` if you do not want to add classes

Comment: the tilde selector is the exact thing I need, and just how you wrote it, I can't use :nth-child I think if I don't know exactly how much child I have, right ?

Comment: True. Classes are preferable